# Do ActiveRecord support transitivity?(Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

If I have 3 elements

A-->B-->C

A has many B, B has many C, hence A has many C. Is it enough to define in

-A model

A has many B

-B model

B has many C

-C model

C belongs_to B

or should I also add the 2 statements

in A controller  A has many C
and in C  belongs_to A ????

Comment: The db design comes down to how you want to use the relationships. If you want to get from A  <-> C without going through B, then you have to create an explicit A <-> C relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

Yes and No.

Yes, you can use: `has_many :c, through: :b`

If proper scope has been defined in the `B` model.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

But you should avoid that because you will be overriding the Demeter Law. And it's not a good idea to make objects too wise about relationships they don't own.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter

Comment: I wasn't asking about that kind of association. I just asked if A has many B's and a B has many C's  if you have to specify that A has many C's in A model and that C belongs to A in C controller

Comment: That's why you have two answers: yes and no. There is no direct associations between models, but you can trick it using the through method.

Comment: but is it worth it?...... I think that type of association is intended for intermmediate id's tables

Comment: No it's not. That's why I'm quoting demeters law. If you are trying to find C models related to A. You should do: B.where(a_id: id).c

Comment: Did this solved your question? If not, could you please post the answer so I can upvote it if correct?